# How to select with version of Zurb Foundation to use for a CodeKit + Compass + Sass Project

Tags: rubygems, zurb-foundation, compass-geolocation, codekit

I was hoping to use the new version (v4) of Foundation for a responsive project I'm working on so I installed v4 via `gem install zurb-foundation` the other day and got CodeKit up and running with it. However, my client has asked that we support IE8 (God help me) because we still have a significant amount of traffic showing up in analytics.

Version 4 of Foundation doesn't support IE8 because its Mobile-First. V3 works differently and can still support IE8.

So i'm trying to figure out how to back track. I installed the latest V3 Foundation GEM via `gem install zurb-foundation -v 3.2.5` but I am not sure how to force CodeKit + Compass to use V3 instead of V4.

Also, when I set up my new project with V4 I had created a COMPASS project in CodeKit and then via the terminal followed this commands to build the Foundation framework in the new Compass project folder:

```
1. Add require "zurb-foundation" to your config.rb file
2. cd path/to/your-project
3. run compass install foundation
```

So now that I have GEMS for v3 and v4 in my system, how can I just work with 3 for this project and set up the folder similarly.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated. I'm fairly new to using CodeKit + Compass + SASS, so be gentle and feel free to be as verbose as you like :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Config.rb in a foundation project is a simple ruby environment file, so selecting the version of zurb-foundation is the same as requiring a specific version of any other gem.

```
gem 'zurb-foundation', '=3.2'
require 'zurb-foundation'
```

Comment: Seems too easy! :) Thanks for the tip. When I reinstall Foundation 4 I'll definitely give this a try. Thanks...and sorry for the late reply!

Answer (score 6):

Dave, I struggled with this for a long time before I had the time to take a break from work to figure it out.  At times I'm using Foundation 2, 3 and 4 on different projects.  Best thing I found was to use bundles. After finally figuring it out though I found this article on ZURB's docs [Goto section Running multiple versions](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html)

First, if you don't have bundler installed yet run `gem install bundler`

Now say for instance I'm creating a new compass zurb-foundation project 'flowershop'

create the directory flowershop `mkdir flowershop && cd flowershop`

create a new file `Gemfile` with the contents

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "zurb-foundation", "4.0.9"
gem "compass"
```

you could also use any other version here.  Foundation 2 for example:

`gem "ZURB-foundation", "2.2.1.4"`

then run the command `bundle install`, it should then install those gems for you
then you can run all your compass commands prefixed with `bundle execute`.

So to create a new compass project with foundation run

`bundle exec compass create . -r zurb-foundation --using foundation`

and then to watch your new product you again prefix the compass command

`bundle exec compass watch .`

Personally, I like using the alias I created for `becw` to `bundle execute compass watch`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I somehow missed these (Gotta check my email updates settings or my spam settings). I really appreciate the tips. I temporarily removed the Foundation 4 Gem which has me working right now. But I like this suggestion of using Bundler. but I think for my case of using Code Kit that the other very simple suggestions is the way I need to do it. Thanks for the reply.